# ORA-19504: failed to create file "bh2jk0h7_1_1"

Tags: backup, rman, oracle-19c, bash

I want to create a script to get incremental backup of the remote Oracle database every week. I save this command in *rman_command.sh* and give permission to it:

```
 BACKUP INCREMENTAL LEVEL 0 DATABASE PLUS ARCHIVELOG FORMAT '/home/oracle/backup_oracle_process/backup_files/%U';
```

Then I run this script that have this content,*script_backup.sh*:

```
  #!/bin/bash
  export ORACLE_HOME=/home/oracle/oracle_database_client
  export PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/bin:$PATH
  rman target sys/pA55w0rd@//172.28.10.22:1521/DSLDB22 @rman_command.sh
  exit;
```

Also I run these commands to give permission to the folder for saving backup files:

```
  chmod +x backup_oracle_process/*
  chown -R root backup_oracle_process/*
```

But,when run *bash script_backup.sh* I receive this error:

```
  Starting backup at 20-FEB-24
  current log archived
  using target database control file instead of recovery catalog
  allocated channel: ORA_DISK_1
  channel ORA_DISK_1: SID=273 device type=DISK
  channel ORA_DISK_1: starting archived log backup set
  channel ORA_DISK_1: specifying archived log(s) in backup set
 input archived log thread=1 sequence=1464 RECID=1 STAMP=1161427056
 input archived log thread=1 sequence=1465 RECID=2 STAMP=1161427247
 input archived log thread=1 sequence=1466 RECID=3 STAMP=1161427335
 input archived log thread=1 sequence=1467 RECID=4 STAMP=1161427356
 input archived log thread=1 sequence=1468 RECID=5 STAMP=1161429542
 channel ORA_DISK_1: starting piece 1 at 20-FEB-24
 RMAN-00571: ===========================================================
 RMAN-00569: =============== ERROR MESSAGE STACK FOLLOWS ===============
 RMAN-00571: ===========================================================
 RMAN-03002: failure of backup plus archivelog command at 02/20/2024 11:17:55
 ORA-19504: failed to create file "/home/oracle/backup_oracle_process/backup_files/bh2jk0h7_1_1"
 ORA-27040: file create error, unable to create file
 Linux-x86_64 Error: 2: No such file or directory
 Additional information: 1
```

Would you please guide me how to solve the problem?

Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest that this is *wrong*:

> chown -R **root** backup_oracle_process/*

[With a couple of well-documented exceptions] Any and all directories (and files) that your database works with should be owned by the account under which your database process *runs*.  By default, that's usually "**oracle**".
It definitely *should not* be **root**.

Comment: W., I did that comment but it did not solve the problem.

Comment: Did what, exactly?  Putting the execute permission ("+x") on a directory is required to "get into" it.  Putting the "write" permission ("+w") on it might be more useful if you intend to do anything in it (like create a file).

Comment: W., nothing is changed.